# Can't ping my domain on Route53?

Tags: amazon-route53

I have a domain set up in Route 53, named bizatspeed.com

I've deleted and recreated a hosted zone for that domain and then copied the DNS names in the NS record to the Name Servers for the domain (not the hosted zone).

I've attached two pictures of the domain registration page and the hosted zone respectively.

When I try to ping the domain bizatspeed.com it tells me the host is unknown.

Any help would be appreciated.

Screenshots of my current setting for domain

[image]

Screenshots of my current setting for Hosted Zone

[image]
Thanks.
M.

Comment: You aren't showing any `A` records here, so that would be the expected behavior until you create one.

Comment: I'm not clear. What should I put in the A record? I'm trying to ping bizatspeed.com. Isn't an A record an Alias record where you name something as something else, e.g. I can declare an A record www.bizatspeed.com pointing to bizatspeed.com?

Comment: An `A` record is an **Address** record that tells the Internet what the IP address(es) of your site is (are).  It can be an Alias in Route 53... but that's simply a pointer to another A record.

Answer (score 1):

Your hosted zone is missing an A record. A stands for "Address", not "Alias". An A record is used to map a host (say, bizatspeed.com) to an IPv4 address.

Suppose the IP of your web server is 257.258.259.260. Then create an A record for your hosted zone as shown below (note that you have to choose "Alias" as 'No'):

[image]

In case your web site is served by an Amazon resource (an Elastic Load Balancer, an S3 static website, or the nearest CloudFront edge location), then create an A record for your hosted zone as shown below (note that you have to choose "Alias" as 'Yes'; under the "Alias Target" field select the AWS resource that serves your website):

[image]